# SQL Column Datatypes

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to validate if the datatype of every value in a column matches the datatype of the column itself. But I figured if I do something like `DESCRIBE table_name`, it should give me the datatype of every column and all the values in a column should conform to its datatype. What I mean is, if I were to have a column called ID which is INT and I change one of the values to 'a', the column's datatype should change from INT correct?
Thanks!

Comment: Consider using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: No, it should give an error. That's the purpose of the data type on the columns.

Answer (score 2):

> What I mean is, if I were to have a column called ID which is INT and I change one of the values to 'a', the column's datatype should change from INT correct?

No, not on modern versions (v5.7 and later) of MySQL. Data types are concrete, and don't change based on the data inside of them. Rather it's the other way around, data types enforce what data is allowed to go inside of them.

In your example, the `UPDATE` query would fail with a relevant error explicitly stating that you cannot set the column value to that data value.

If you were to disable strict mode (or were using v5.6 or earlier), then in your example, the value of the data stored in the `INT` column would be `0`, as discussed in [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-invalid-data.html):

> If you try to store a string that does not start with a number into a numeric column, MySQL Server stores 0.

Comment: Got it! Which means that by virtue of data types being concrete, all the data in a column will be of the column's data type?

Comment: @VedantRaghavan Yes.

Comment: How do I check if strict mode is enabled?

Comment: Actually, if you try to insert "a" into an INT, it will convert to "0".  Similarly, "123xyz456" will be treated as "123" because that is what it sees at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @VedantRaghavan, `SELECT @@sql_mode;` and read about strict mode here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict